# Euler charateristic of the universe

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, topology, gauss-bonnet

According to [Gauss-Bonnet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_gravity), the volume integral

$$\int_M d^4x\sqrt{-g}(R^{abcd}R_{abcd}-4R^{ab}R_{ab}+R^2)=\chi(M)$$

$\chi(M)$ is the Euler characteristic of the manifold $M$.

Let us now consider a subset $S$ of the universe, whose metric is

$$ds^2=-dt^2+a^2(t)(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)$$

$S$ is a four dimensional subspace of the universe which is bounded by two spacelike hypersurface at $t=t_1$ and $t=t_2$. The spatial volume of $S$ is finite, bounded by timelike hypersurfaces $x=x_1$ and $x=x_2$, etc..

A simple calculation reveals that $\chi(S)\propto\dot a^3$. However, the subset $S$ is simply connected, so its topology is trivial, and $\chi(S)=0$. What is wrong with my calculation or understanding?

Comment: More on [spacetime topology](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacetime+topology).

Comment: The ordinary Gauss-Bonnet theorem in two dimensions has a surface term, which you can only omit if you have a compact manifold without boundary. The WP article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem only states the generalization for the case of a compact manifold without boundary. Maybe this is the problem. Your S has a boundary, but you didn't compute the boundary term.

Comment: Be careful that the Gauss Bonnet theorem does not work as is on Lorentzian metrics

Comment: @BenCrowell What's the form of the boundary term?

Comment: @Slereah It may be true that Gauss-Bonnet theorem fails on Lorentzian metric. However, it is well-known that a Gauss-Bonnet term is a total divergence in 4 dimensional spacetime, so it is called a topological term. So it seems that this theorem applies.